# How to do Tesseract Ocr on stored image of Mongo DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, ocr, tesseract

I have stored image in Mongodb as binary data and unable to perform ocr on that. I was tried out in a two different ways.

1. I was used individual, @Getmapping+@Asyn to get a image based on object id.
2. The second one was used as stand alone program [public static void main] based on  Uri of Mongodb.

Both the case unable to did that. **Is anyone knew how to do that in a right way ??.**

```
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;  
    private String name;    
    private Binary image;}} getters & setters , constructors
```

**CONTROLLER** [worked perfectly for upload image and retrieved image as binary data]

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
User createUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
{   User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setImage(new Binary(file.getBytes()));     
    return userRepository.save(user);
}   
@GetMapping("/retrive")
String getImage(@RequestParam String id) {  
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);
    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();      
    return encoder.encodeToString(user.get().getImage().getData()); 
}
```

**CONTROLLER FOR OCR [result shown 200 OK in postman but not executed the text from mongodb ]**

```
 @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
 public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor()
  { return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();    
   }


@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")    
@GetMapping("/image")   
public String asyncMethodWithConfiguredExecutor(@RequestParam String id) 
{   
    System.out.println("Execute method" + Thread.currentThread().getId());      
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);      
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();          
    try {

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(user.get().getImage().getData());
        BufferedImage bufferImg = ImageIO.read(bais);           
        String imgText = instance.doOCR(bufferImg);         
        return imgText;
                }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return "Error while reading image";
    }   }
```

**2. MAIN FUCTION [MY SECOND WAY- Result "unsupported image for ocr can't read it"]**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowApplication 
{   
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{       
SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);    
Mongo mongodb = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);                
DB db = mongodb.getDB("test-db");   
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("user");     
File image = new File("mongodb://localhost:27017//test-db//user");
 Tesseract tessInst = new Tesseract();     
 tessInst.setDatapath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata");    
    try {
          String result= tessInst.doOCR(image);
          System.out.println(result);
       } catch (TesseractException a) {
          System.err.println(a.getMessage());   
    }   } }
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPekD.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWb97.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for Mongo for the content storage piece.  Spring Content is to unstructured data (documents, videos, images), what Spring Data is to structured data.  It provides an abstraction over Storage.  Giving you the same programming model in order to achieve REST-based content services quickly and easily.

You can add it to your project like this:

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0</version>    <!-- 1.0.0.M3 for Spring Boot 2.2 -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0</version>    <!-- 1.0.0.M3 for Spring Boot 2.2 -->
</dependency>
```

Make sure you have a GridFsTemplate bean present in your application context (Images will be stored in Mongo's GridFS).  Mongo Storage and REST API are enabledas follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoStores
@Import(org.springframework.content.rest.config.RestConfiguration.class) // Enable REST API
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
      return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
   }
   ...
```

To allow content to be associated with your User entity, give it the following attributes:

> User.java

```
public class User {    

    @Id
    private String id;      
    //private Binary image;    replace this with -->

    @ContentId
    private String contentId;

    @ContentLength 
    private long contentLength = 0L;

    @MimeType
    private String mimeType;
```

Add a store interface:

> UserImageStore.java

```
public interface UserImageStore extends ContentStore<User, String> {
}
```

When your application starts Spring Content will see the dependencies on the Mongo/REST modules and it will inject a GridFS implementation of the `UserImageStore`, as well as an implementation of a Controller that supports full CRUD functionality and maps those operations onto the `UserImageStore` interface.  The REST endpoints will be available at `/users`.

i.e.

`curl -X PUT /users/{userId} -F "file=@/some/image.jpg"` will create or update a user image for user `userId`

`curl -X GET /users/{userId}` will fetch the image again

`curl -X DELETE /users/{userId}` will delete the image

> Tesseract

With Spring Content in place you can then use its event handling mechanism to plug in your tesseract OCR:

```
@StoreEventHandler
public static class OcrHandler {

   @Autowired
   private UserImageStore images;

   @HandleAfterSetContent
   @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public void handleAfterSetContent(User user) {

      tesseract.TessBaseAPI api = new tesseract.TessBaseAPI();

      // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
      if (api.Init("/path/to/your/trained/data", "eng") != 0) {
          ...
      }

      byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
      try {
         // get the image from the user for ocr processing
         bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(images.get(user));
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         ...
      }
      lept.PIX pix = pixReadMem(bytes, bytes.length);
      api.SetImage(pix);

      BytePointer outText = api.GetUTF8Text();

      // use outText.getString() containing the ocr result

      api.End();
      outText.deallocate();
      pixDestroy(pix);
   }
}
```

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  They use Spring Content for the filesystem but the Storage Modules are interchangeable.  The Mongo reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/mongo-index.html).  There is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).  And an example project [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples/tree/master/spring-eg-content-mongo).

HTH

Comment: Hi Paul Warren, Application started successfully and used 
 "http://localhost:8080/users/vijay" with image file in post man  form data while hit send, The result shown as 404 not found error. I was added  jar and dependencies like spring-content-mongo,spring-content-rest,content-store-api  everything correctly but the postman not accepted url.Is it accepted without any database mentioned in application properties and we not used any @Restcontroller for upload and retrieve image. and ocr controller also shown error in tesseract it's not accept the dependency. can pls guide me

Comment: it will be difficult to tell without looking at it more closely.  you should not need to create any controllers, that is all done for you.  sounds like some beans are not being registered.  no database required either.  should use gridfs.  the tesseract event handler is an example only.  but if you can reproduce the issue with a small project pls push it to your org in github and then reference it in a github issue to spring-content.

Comment: a couple of simple things to check: postman; is the upload a multipart upload?  url; is `vijay` really the userId?